# Assign (value, key) names in Python Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

How can you assign (value:key) names in python dictionaries?

Are lists a good option?

EX:

```
animals [name, speed]

animals {'Falcon':'fast','Turtle': 'slow'}

for key in animals:

    if animals[speed] == 'fast':
        print animal[key], "is fast"
```

Comment: `animals [name, speed]` and `animals {'Falcon': 'fast', 'Turtle': 'slow'}` does not make any sense

Comment: What is it you would like to do?

Comment: @James Bvsh: I don't really understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Have you read https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries?

Comment: You don't need to reverse the keys and values; you just need to correctly check the key you do have: `if animals[key] == 'fast': print key, "is fast"`.

Answer (score 0):

not entirely sure what you mean; but if you have a dictionary

```
animals = {'Falcon':'fast','Turtle': 'slow'}
```

you can always extend it by:

```
animals['Snail'] = 'slow'
```

and print the fast ones with:

```
for animal, speed in animals.items():
    if speed == 'fast':
        print( animal, "is fast")
```